# Expected an identifier.dart(missing_identifier) Flutter, dart

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, syntax-error

I have been diligently working on this code, trying to ensure that it runs smoothly without any errors. However, despite my best efforts, the code is still malfunctioning and generating errors. It has been quite frustrating for me, as I have invested a considerable amount of time and effort into this project. As a result, I am now turning to you for assistance in identifying the problem and finding a solution.

I have already attempted to modify the parentheses and brackets in the code, as I believed this may be the root of the issue. Despite my attempts, the code still refuses to cooperate. Therefore, I implore you to please help me locate the error in the code, so that we can finally get it working as it should. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(TodoApp());

class TodoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Todo App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TodoListScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class Todo {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  bool isDone;

  Todo({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.isDone = false,
  });

  factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Todo(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      isDone: json['isDone'],
    );
  }
}

class TodoListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodoListScreenState createState() => _TodoListScreenState();
}

class _TodoListScreenState extends State<TodoListScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _todoTitleController = TextEditingController();
  final List<Todo> _todos = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchTodos();
  }

  void _fetchTodos() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://todoapp-api.apps.k8s.gu.se/todos'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonList = jsonDecode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
      final todos = jsonList.map((json) => Todo.fromJson(json)).toList();
      setState(() {
        _todos.clear();
        _todos.addAll(todos);
      });
    } else {
      // Handle error
    }
  }

  void _addTodo() async {
    final newTodoTitle = _todoTitleController.text.trim();
    if (newTodoTitle.isNotEmpty) {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://todoapp-api.apps.k8s.gu.se/todos'),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: jsonEncode({'title': newTodoTitle, 'isDone': false}),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        final newTodo = Todo.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        setState(() {
          _todos.add(newTodo);
        });
      } else {
        // Handle error
      }
      _todoTitleController.clear();
    }
  }

  void _toggleTodoStatus(Todo todo) async {
    final response = await http.patch(
      Uri.parse('https://todoapp-api.apps.k8s.gu.se/todos/${todo.id}'),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: jsonEncode({'isDone': !todo.isDone}),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        todo.isDone = !todo.isDone;
      });
    } else {
      // Handle error
    }
  }

  void _deleteTodo(Todo todo) async {
    final response = await http.delete(Uri.parse('https://todoapp-api.apps.k8s.gu.se/todos/${todo.id}'));
    if (response.statusCode == 204) {
      setState(() {
        _todos.remove(todo);
      });
    } else {
      // Handle error
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todo List'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _todos.length,
        itemBuilder: ()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Is it a compile error, runtime error? Which line?

Comment: This does not look like "Angular Dart". Are you sure about that? What does "flutter-animation" and "flutter-dependencies" have to do with it?

Comment: @nvoigt the last seven rows.

Comment: What do you think "itemBuilder: ()" does? What do you *want* it to do?

Comment: @nvoigt i just want the todo to work properly, should i remove it then.

Comment: Wel, if you remove it, it will not show anything. I guess you want to show your ToDos?

Comment: yes exacly @nvoigt